# Access Google Artifact repository image from onprem K8S using Workload Identity Federation

Tags: kubernetes, google-artifact-registry, workload-identity

I have set up K3S cluster (some bare metal k8s cluster) on my laptop. I am planning to setup Workload identity federation  between this cluster and my GCP Artifact repository , so I will be able to pull images successfully onto my onprem cluster.

First, I have followed this documentation https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation-with-kubernetes#kubernetes_1 and able to execute till end, got the token printed. So the configuration is successful.

As a next step, I have simply made change to image in the pod.yaml example and provided Artifact repository Reader access to the service account set in the above above example.  When I delete the pod and applied the yaml file again, container fails.

```
failed to authorize, failed to fetch anonymous token: unexecuted status from GET request to https://us-west-docker.pkg.dev/v2/token? xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Image exists in GAR and the version are correct, I am able to pull the same image with version mentioned using docker on my laptop.

Can you please let me know what else am I missing to download an image from GAR using workload identity federation ?

Thanks
Sri

Comment: Since the `Artifact Registry Reader` role is given to the service account which fetches the image from repositories, the issue might be in pod’s yaml. Can you check the yaml file has the service account that has granted the mentioned role and the image reference too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, it did. First I completed the exercise which has the SA that is mapped with workload identity fed. I simply changed the image to the one in GAR.

Comment: I have editted the answer according to your comments. can you please check and let me know, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error `failed to authorize, failed to fetch anonymous token` might be occurring because the access token is a short-lived token to authenticate with Artifact Registry. Since the token is valid for 60 minutes, you should request it less than an hour before you use it to connect with Artifact Registry. Also check for the below troubleshooting steps:

1. **Check Workload Identity Federation:**
   You must [enable](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#verify_the_setup) Workload Identity Federation for GKE on clusters and node pools using the Cloud CLI or Cloud console. Workload identity federation for GKE must be enabled at the cluster level before you can enable WIF for GKE on node pools.

- To enable workload identity federation for GKE on an existing cluster, run the command:

  ```
   gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER\_NAME   --region=COMPUTE\_REGION  --workload-pool=PROJECT\_ID.svc.id.goog
  ```

2. **Authentication:** If you are configuring Docker to authenticate to the Artifact Registry Docker repositories, Docker requires privileged access to interact with registries. If you are using Linux or Windows VM, add the user to run Docker commands to the Docker security group. For Linux command is

   ```
    sudo usermod -a -G docker ${USER}
   ```

Refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#before_you_begin) for Windows and MacOS machines.

3. If you're using service account keys, try to use an [access token](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/helm/authentication#token) to reduce the risk of unauthorized access to your artifacts.
4. Check for the [third-party clients](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#third-party) like Docker which need to configure both permissions and authentication.

**EDIT:**

Even though you are not using GKE, you still need to enable WIF for your on-prem Kubernetes cluster. This involves creating a service account in GCP and binding it to the **gke-connect role**. WIF allows Kubernetes pods to access Google Cloud resources using the identity of the service account associated with the pod. Also make sure service account has the necessary permissions to pull images from the repository.

Also if the issuer URL in the WIF configuration is incorrect. The issuer URL should be the URL of the Kubernetes cluster that the pod is running in. Check the output of the command : `kubectl cluster-info` which will include the issuer URL.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed steps. I am not using GKE but using onprem kubernetes. Do I still need to enable WIF for GKE ? 

Also I have a pod definition like this in my onprem k8s which has credentials path given but I am not using any command to pass credentials as part of gcloud....  I was assuming that K8S takes care of that with SA while pulling the image . Also I believe the token in this case is generated by Kubernetes cluster and is being authenticated by google cloud (WIF) isn't it ?

Comment: In the provider(WIF configuration) I gave issuer as the url of kubernetes, that made me think issuer is kubernetes itself. To let google cloud validate that we get Cluster's JWK token and pass it in Workload identity fed(WIF) configuration.

All the steps, I followed are here and the pod definition too.
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation-with-kubernetes#kubernetes_1